# Plain MEAN Stack or a MEAN Framework like mean.io?

Tags: mean-stack, mean.io

I have very decent HTML and CSS skills and a basic understanding of JavaScript. I'm currently designing a system where different users can store an inventory list (a separate list for each user).

I started with plain Mongo, Express, Angular and Node Stack. But when researching about user authentication in MEAN-Stack I stumbled across Mean.io which seems to have a build-in user auth/management.

Is it usefull for a beginner to start with such a MEAN Framework or better to stay at the basics for a first try?

Answer (score 0):

MEAN frameworks like MEAN.io or MEAN.js are great for structuring an app but you still have to understand how everything works. It may be better to go with tutorials from scratch to learn then use a framework once you want to actually build an app. Start with a node/express server using a simple html/js page to understand API creation then add angular to learn the frontend stuff. This will help you understand what MEAN.xx is doing with regards to the frontend vs backend. MEAN.js for example puts all the backend (E and N) stuff in the server/ folders and the frontend (A) stuff in client/ folders.